# ArrayIndexOutOfBounds on getChildView

Tags: java, android

I have encounter an intermittent bug on Android.
This is happening sometimes when I load a screen.
Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the code:

```
private void setSimpleAdapter(){
    simpleAdapter = new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(mContext, mListParent, R.layout.subheader, mFromParent, mToParent,
            mListChild, getChildLayout(), mFromChild, mToChild){


        @Override
        public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.subheader, parent, false);
            }
            View view = super.getGroupView(groupPosition, isExpanded, convertView, parent);
            updateParent(view, mSubSections == null);
            return view;
        }

        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(getChildLayout(), parent, false);
            }

            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_two_lines_description)).setMaxLines(1);
            
            View view = super.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, isLastChild, convertView, parent);
            updateChild(view, mRecentEntryList.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition));
            return view;
        }
    };
}
```

I have tried adding validation on getChildView like this:
`code`

```
        @Override
        public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(getChildLayout(), parent, false);
            }

            ((TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_two_lines_description)).setMaxLines(1);
            
            if(groupPosition < mRecentEntryList.size()) {
                if (childPosition < mRecentEntryList.get(groupPosition).size()) {
                    View view = super.getChildView(groupPosition, childPosition, isLastChild, convertView, parent);
                    updateChild(view, mRecentEntryList.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition));
                    return view;
                }
            }
            
            return null
        }
```

````
And this is the logs:
```code
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.unit4.timesheet, PID: 31291
    java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10
        at android.widget.SimpleExpandableListAdapter.bindView(SimpleExpandableListAdapter.java:249)
        at android.widget.SimpleExpandableListAdapter.getChildView(SimpleExpandableListAdapter.java:229)
        at com.unit4.timesheet.adapter.QuickEntrySimpleAdapterHelper$1.getChildView(QuickEntrySimpleAdapterHelper.java:107)
        at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:451)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2405)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:2071)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:797)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:859)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1814)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2202)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1183)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:870)
        at android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:889)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1103)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:779)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3080)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2590)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7598)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
````

Below is the line 249 code which is in SimpleExpandableListAdapter.java
[image]

Comment: We can't see your IDE from where we're sitting. Maybe you can do yourself a favor and identify which line in your code is line 249.

Comment: In both `getChildView()` and `getGroupView()`, you should not be inflating the layouts yourself. `SimpleExpandableListAdapter` takes care of that in the `super` calls. If you want to modify the items further, then you should be doing that on the `View view` returned from those `super` calls, not on `convertView`. Get rid of the whole `if (convertView == null)` block in both methods.

Comment: Hi @MarsAtomic, Thanks for responding to this. I have added the screenshot of the code.

Comment: I have tried removing only if (convertView == null) block and removing both the @Override methods but result the same error.
Fyi, this is legacy code, I check on others Adapter and they have the same implementation, but I'm still searching why it's only happening on this adapter helper.

Comment: Nah, that was just FYI. Sorry, that was confusing. Your stack trace seems to be saying that the `to` and `from` arrays are different lengths.

Comment: I rechecked it again it's solved now. Thanks for you explanation @MikeM, it was the `to` array length is not passing the correct values.